# Crystal Report just have one line?

Tags: crystal-reports, datatable

```
            OpenConnect();
            OleDbDataAdapter olda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from RECORD where LIC_PLATE='GE 320'", con);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            olda.Fill(dataset);
            cr1.SetDataSource(dataset.Tables[0]);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
            CloseConnect();
```

I had only one line in my report. How can I solve this problem ? I checked that I had too many records that has LIC_PLATE= GE 320

Answer (score 1):

Check if your fields are not grouped and that they are in the details section. Maybe they are in a group section or in a Page section,